# Computing a matrix to convert an (x,y) point on an ellipse to a circle

Tags: circles, conic-sections

I have an ellipse defined by its semi-major axis, inclination, and position angle.  The ellipse is centered on the origin.

I would like to solve for a matrix that converts this ellipse to a circle.

Hence if I have (x,y) on this ellipse, I need to convert it to (x', y') on a circle.

It is not straightforward to set x' = x and y' = y cos (inclination) because the ellipse semi-major and semi-minor axes are not collinear with the X- and Y- axes but are inclined by the position angle.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections

Comment: There are more than one linear transformations which will do this.  However the information described does not uniquely determine an ellipse.  In addition to the semi-major axis, its inclination to the x-axis, and the center at the origin, we need to know either the semi-minor axis or the eccentricity.

Comment: The semi-minor axis can be determined from the inclination, e.g. b = a cos i

Answer (score 2):

"Inclination" here seems to be connected with the angle $i$ at which a cone is intercepted by a plane to produce the ellipse, but I'm not familiar with the term.  At any rate the OP says (see Comment above) that the semi-minor axis can be expressed as $b = a \cos i$.  In what follows, we assume this has been done.

Confusion arises from the subsequent wording that "the ellipse semi-major and semi-minor axes are not collinear with the X- and Y- axes but are inclined by the position angle."  Notation for this *position* angle is not provided in the Question, so let's supply it here, and in doing so let's refer instead to it as the *angle of rotation* $\alpha$.  Specifically, since the ellipse is "centered on the origin", we define $\alpha \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ to be the angle between the semi-major axis and the positive X-axis.

More concretely: the endpoints of the major axis, centered as they are on the origin, are expressed by:

$$ \pm a (\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha) $$

The first step is then "unrotation" by this angle of rotation, a linear transformation on Cartesian coordinates expressed by the following matrix multiplication:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\ -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} $$

Clearly applying this transformation to the endpoints of the major axis (see above) will map them to $( \pm a, 0)$, thereby putting both major and minor axes in line with the $X$- and $Y$-coordinate axes, respectively.

In this "standard position" the ellipse can easily be transformed into a circle by scaling the X- or Y-coordinate or both.  E.g. the mapping $(X,Y) \rightarrow (bX,aY)$ will produce a circle of radius $ab$ by scaling both coordinates.  Combining these operations gives a matrix multiplication:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} X' \\ Y' \end{bmatrix} =
   \begin{bmatrix} b\cos \alpha & b\sin \alpha \\ -a\sin \alpha & a\cos \alpha
   \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} $$
**Optional:** Further equal scaling of both coordinates by a nonzero factor will change the radius accordingly (but preserve circularity) and might be desirable if a particular radius is desired.

Finally this circle may itself be rotated around the origin through any angle, using a linear transformation similar to the "unrotation" described above.  However this step is unnecessary if the goal was merely to map the original ellipse to a circle.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it prior to reading this post but your exposition is very clearly written and much appreciated.

Comment: then, you should accept the answer